# Copy the contents of std::vector<char> into a char* buffer?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have an std::vector. I want to copy the contents of the vector into a char* buffer of a certain size.

Is there a safe way to do this?

Can I do this?

```
memcpy(buffer, _v.begin(), buffer_size);
```

or this?

```
std::copy(_v.begin(), _v.end(), buffer); // throws a warning (unsafe)
```

or this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < _v.size(); i++)
{
  *buffer = _v[i];
  buffer++;
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: My C++-fu is a little rusty, but wouldn't `char* str = &_v[0];` do the job?

Comment: @Polynomial Probably, at least at first. If the vector ever reallocates its buffer, the location may change, and if the vector is destroyed, the pointer is invalid. It's risky enough that it's probably not a *good* idea.

Comment: @Polynomial: That will not copy the vector into a different buffer, it will just grab the address of the internal buffer in the vector.

Comment: @Polynomial: That will work perfectly well for the moment and even be much faster, however, it will break the moment you add some data to the vector and exceed its capacity. At that time, it will allocate a new block and free the one you point to.

Comment: The real question is: Why do you want to use a `char*` buffer? `std::vector` is much better in (almost) every way.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I don't tend to deal with much C or C++ these days, so I hadn't considered the reallocation issues. I guess `&_v[0]` is still useful, though. It can be nice for cases where you just want to perform a quick operation on an `std::vector` where your function only takes `char*`, and you're not worried about race conditions. Still, best practice is a proper copy.

Comment: @krebstar: what warning do you get ? A pointer is a model of `RandomIterator` which comprises the requirements for an `OutputIterator`, so a pointer is certainly valid for the 3rd argument of `std::copy`. Could you show us the text of the warning?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I am getting this warning: warning C4996: 'std::copy': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'

Comment: @krebstar: Ah okay. Warnings in `/W4` (ie with and ID superior to 4000) are more often than not just noise. As you can read, it just warns you that it is *your* responsability to ensure that the destination buffer is large enough, because using a bare pointer instead of a more advanced type prevents VC++ to insert debug code to check it for you. I would advise only going to `/W3` if you don't want to be drown.

Comment: The answer to this depends on what you want to do with the char* buffer. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Polynomial no, not really. The problem is that the term "char* buffer" is misleading: a `char*` **isn't** a buffer. It is a pointer to the buffer. Your code says "point to the internal buffer used by the `std::vector` instance". The intended effect is "copy data into the buffer that is currently being pointed at".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry I guess I should have said "char buffer" pointed to by a char*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
std::copy(_v.begin(), _v.end(), buffer);
```

This is preferred way to do this in C++. It is safe to copy this way if `buffer` is large enough.

Comment: This isn't enough: you should add a \0 character at the end.

Comment: @Nawaz But it is reasonable to assume they may be treated as such. Not doing so is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @AdamZalcman: It is not reasonable. What if the vector contents many `\0`?

Comment: @AdamZalcman: Also, if that is reasonable, then the initial choice of `std::vector<char>` is wrong to begin with, as `std::string` would be a *better* choice in case if `char*` needs to be treated with c-string.

Comment: @Nawaz vector<size> maintains size information while char* doesn't. It wouldn't be wise to operate on such a sequence of chars using char* in the first place. char* is more than just a pointer: it has implied semantics of a c-string.

Comment: @AdamZalcman: `_v` may already contain `\0` at the end - then no need to add more `\0`

Comment: @AdamZalcman: As I said, in that case `std::string` would be a better choice, THEN you can add `\0` at the end when making a copy of it, and storing it in `char*`.

Comment: Nawas is right, the char* i am working with has many \0s.. it is not a character string in the C sense of the word..

Comment: My question is, is vector<char> guaranteed to be a contiguous block of memory? Is there any way to do this that doesn't give out warnings? Perhaps an std::copy_s() function?

Comment: @AdamZalcman: No. I don't think it is sloppy answer. When I see `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::string`, I assume that the vector 's content is not guaranteed to be c-string.

Comment: @krebstar: Yes. `vector<char>` is guaranteed to be a contiguous block of memory?.

Comment: @Adam: There are too many things we assume while answering question. For example, in your answer, you assumed that the allocated memory will be deallocated with `delete`. But you didn't *state* that, did you? (neither did I)

Comment: @Nawaz Your assumption about the lack of the need for a null-terminal is directly related to the code you wrote. The reader will hopefully be warned by this discussion which has now grown far too long for a trivial issue like null-terminal.

Comment: @AdamZalcman: The problem with your line of thinking is that when you see `char*`, it is you who assume it to be c-string. But when I see `char*`, I only see `char*`. No assumption. As I said, `char*` doesn't necessarily mean c-string.

Comment: @Nawaz You're missing the point: I know `char*` may or may not be a c-string. The point is that the reader of the code and the answer may easily be misled (due to overwhelmingly frequent use of `char*` to refer to c-strings).

Comment: If you guys want to have a discussion of how most people interpret `char *`, please move it to chat.

Comment: Note that in Visual C, using std::copy() as suggested above will likely cause warning C4996

Comment: To settle the above dispute, I will point out that I found this answer while looking for advice on how to handle arbitrary data read from a network socket, which comes in as a `std::vector<unsigned char>` buffer but needs to be copied into a `char *` buffer.

Comment: This may also be accomplished with `std::ranges::copy(_v, buffer)` if `buffer` is a fixed-size array.  [(source)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/copy)

Answer (score 11):

If you just need `char*`, then you can do this:

```
char *buffer=&v[0];//v is guaranteed to be a contiguous block of memory.
//use buffer
```

Note changing data pointed to by `buffer` changes the vector's content also!

Or if you need a *copy*, then allocate a memory of size equal to `v.size()` bytes, and use `std::copy`:

```
 char *buffer = new char[v.size()];
 std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), buffer);
```

**Dont forget to `delete []buffer;` after you're done, else you'll leak memory.**

But then why would you invite such a problem which requires you to manage the memory yourself.. especially when you can do better, such as:

```
auto copy = v; // that's simpler way to make copies!!
// and then use copy as new buffer.
// no need to manually delete anything. :-)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The safest way to copy a `vector<char>` into a `char *` buffer is to copy it to another vector, and then use that vector's internal buffer:

```
std::vector<char> copy = _v;
char * buffer = &copy[0];
```

Of course, you can also access `_v`s buffer if you don't actually need to copy the data. Also, beware that the pointer will be invalidated if the vector is resized.

If you need to copy it into a particular buffer, then you'll need to know that the buffer is large enough before copying; there are no bounds checks on arrays. Once you've checked the size, your second method is best. (The first only works if `vector::iterator` is a pointer, which isn't guaranteed; although you could change the second argument to `&_v[0]` to make it work. The third does the same thing, but is more complicated, and probably should be fixed so it doesn't modify `buffer`).

Comment: This is *almost* best. I didn't think that way. +1.

Comment: shortly speaking: beware of such a case:  
`char * buffer;{std::vector<char> copy = _v;buffer = &copy[0];} cout<<buffer;`

Comment: @test30 To clarify, it would help to point out that the copy vector being inside a nested scope is the issue you're warning about. The copy vector is deallocated when the scope closes. If you remove the curly braced scope, this works fine. (Considering this is a non-expert level question.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to assign to `*buffer` for case 3, but that should work. The first one almost certainly won't work.

EDIT: I stand corrected regarding #2.

Comment: Anyway, is there no faster way to do this? doing a for/while loop seems weird.. =/

Answer (score 0):

```
static std::vector<unsigned char> read_binary_file (const std::string filename)
{
    // binary mode is only for switching off newline translation
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    std::streampos file_size;
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    file_size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<unsigned char> vec(file_size);
    vec.insert(vec.begin(),
               std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(file),
               std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>());
    return (vec);
}
```

and then:

```
auto vec = read_binary_file(filename);
auto src = (char*) new char[vec.size()];
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), src);
```

but remember to delete []src later